# MySQL query execution with Prisma taking too long

Tags: mysql, node.js, prisma-graphql

I've built a node-GraphQl server (using GraphQl-yoga) with MySQL database running inside a docker container and I'm using Prisma to interact with it (i.e to perform all sort of DB operations). My db is growing faster with time (7 GB consumed in one month). I have 10 tables and one of them has 600 000 rows and its growing exponentially (almost 20 000 rows are being added to this table each day). As the application starts, it has to fetch the data from this table. Now the problem is that I have to stop and then restart mysql service each day for my application to work properly, otherwise it would either take too much time to load the data (from table with 6 lac rows) or it completely stops working (and again I've to restart MySQL service and then it starts working fine, at-least for one day). I don't know whether its the problem with mysql database and specifically with the table that has 600 000 rows and growing rapidly (i'm new to mysql) or using prisma which performs all queries? Is there any possible way to get rid of this problem (stop and restart mysql service)?

// Table structure in datamodel.prisma file inside prisma folder

```
type Topics {
  id: ID! @unique
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
  locationId: Int
  obj: Json
}
```

Comment: Could you give table structure and what kind of query running in initial stage?

Comment: Firstly restarting the SQL service is not a tennable solution as this would drop all existing query execution plans. When the application starts how much data is initially consumed? would you perhaps beneifit from using some partitioning? a good amount of detail on this can be found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html

Comment: @AnanthCool

I've put the table structure above(in the post) and initially (on the home page), the query runs to fetch the data of last day (latest 24 rows) from db.

Comment: The first step is to get the SQL queries Prisma is performing, and obtain the query plan. Do your tables have indexes?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt raises a very valid point, I assumed you already had indexes in place, but reading over your qustion again, you state that you are new to MySQL, therefore, you need to look at your table structure, and quite rightly the indexes that you have applied, if you are filtering data you need indexes for query performance.

Comment: @aqibjaved Make sure your table column 'createdAt' created as index column. Use 'EXPLAIN' keyword to analyse your MySQL query. It will tell you how much records where scanned to get required results.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how does Prisma API read data from this table.

My simple sugesstion is first you have to read `first` and `last ID` for last date using `createdAt` column and group it using this same column and get `Min` and `Max ID`. In this first read operation select `ID` only.

Then select records between these two ID. So you don't need to read all records each time.